# Pytorch: How to map a model zoo pre-trained model to a new GPU

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to load one of the pre-trained models

```python
model_urls = { 'resnet18': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet18-5c106cde.pth', 'resnet34': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet34-333f7ec4.pth'}
```

When I used the following code, it always loads the model to cuda:0. What if I want to load it to cuda:3?

```python
model = ResNet(BasicBlock, [3, 4, 6, 3]) 
device = 3
model.load_state_dict(model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['resnet34'], 
                      map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage.cuda(device)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you:

```py
device = torch.device('cuda')
model = ResNet(BasicBlock, [3, 4, 6, 3]) 
with torch.cuda.device(3):
    model.load_state_dict(model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['resnet34'], 
                          map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage.cuda(device)))
```

*I think this works for version 0.4.0 and higher, you can check out some further examples in the 0.4.0. migration guide:
https://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html*